# Error during training CNN with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

have an error during training CNN with tensorflow. The error occured at the first epoch. I made snipping of it.

[snipping of error: 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Uz4i.png)
[snipping of error: 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoHhT.png)

here is the code of training:

```
batch_size=256
batch_size_val=256
def generator(xx,yy1,batch_size):
    num_samples = len(xx)
    indices = np.arange(num_samples)
    
    while True:
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
        for start_idx in range(0, num_samples, batch_size):
            i = random.randint(0,23)
            end_idx = min(start_idx + batch_size, num_samples)
            batch_indices = indices[start_idx:end_idx]
            yield xx[:,i:i+48][batch_indices], np.repeat(yy1[:,i*2:i*2+96], batch_size, axis=0)
            
def generator_val(xxv,yyv1,batch_size_val):
    num_samples = len(xxv)
    indices = np.arange(num_samples)
    
    while True:
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
        for start_idx in range(0, num_samples, batch_size_val):
            i = random.randint(0,23)
            end_idx = min(start_idx + batch_size_val, num_samples)
            #print(start_idx,end_idx)
            batch_indices = indices[start_idx:end_idx]
            yield xxv[:,i:i+48][batch_indices], np.repeat(yyv1[:,i*2:i*2+96], batch_size_val, axis=0)
    

checkpoint_val=ModelCheckpoint('CNN_best_val.h5', monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
checkpoint_train=ModelCheckpoint('CNN_best_train.h5', monitor='accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
checkpoint_val_loss=ModelCheckpoint('CNN_best_val_loss.h5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list=[checkpoint_val,checkpoint_train,checkpoint_val_loss]        
            
H=model_final.fit(generator(X_train,Y_YPG_mask,batch_size), 
                validation_data=generator_val(X_test, Y_YPG_mask, batch_size_val),
                callbacks=callbacks_list,
                #sample_weight={'output_2':sample_weights_output2},
                epochs=10, 
                steps_per_epoch=len(X)//batch_size,
                validation_steps=len(X_test)//batch_size_val)
```